# Make size of <main> and <nav> consistent across screen sizes

Tags: html, css

This is probably a very basic question (outing myself as a noob) but I'm stumped. I have a website I'm building where each page has a bunch of text and other elements, and a sidebar navigation that's sticky.

To do this, I've used a `<main>` element which I've formatted as a grid, and allocated some space on the left to the `<nav>` and the rest to the main text etc. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to keep the positioning consistent across screen sizes. I want the size of the whole element (the `<nav>` and the `<main>` to take up roughly the whole screen if on a small laptop screen (e.g. 11") but not necessarily get larger (i.e. the margin expands?) on larger desktop monitors. I want the ~90% of the `<main>` that I have dedicated to the content to stay **centered** on every page it's on, and the `nav` to slightly off-center on the left.

To demonstrate with a reprex, here's what I want it to look like roughly:

[image]

With a smaller laptop-sized screen. However, with a larger screen (e.g. my 27" desktop screen) it looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to use a % margin in the css

```
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15em 1fr;
  max-width: 100em;
  margin: auto 10% auto auto;
}
```

But that's clearly not working. I'm still a html/css newbie, so hoping someone can help me with what I'm sure is quite an easy fix?

I made a [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/colebrookson/pen/qBKLyrL) if that's helpful?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out someone has come up with a good way to do this already!! https://codepen.io/ragdoll/pen/KKXaNP shows how to do it by approximating a `min-margin` even though there isn't any such thing, but it works equivalently